# ASP.NET-MVC ; pass model to $.ajax function to perform server-side validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, ajaxform

I need to do server side validation and that is send model to partial view. I am using $.ajax--> post--> json method to send and handle data, but I am failing to send validation model to partial view.

### ajax method

```
  $('#NewFunctionNavigationForm').submit(function (e) {

   e.preventDefault();

  var DataToPost =  JSON.stringify($('#NewFunctionNavigationForm').serializeObject());

  var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: formURL,
      dataType: "JSON",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: DataToPost,
  })
.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    if (data.Response == "Success") {

        $(this).MyMessageDialog({
            _messageBlockID: "_StatusMessage",
            _messageContent: "Record Been Created Successfully",
            _messageBlockWidth: "300px"
        });

        $('div#_StatusMessage').on('dialogclose', function (event) {
            window.location = "/SystemCore/SystemCoreHome";
        });
    }

})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    $(this).MyMessageDialog({
        _messageBlockID: "_StatusMessage",
        _messageContent: "Error In Creating Record! "+ textStatus + "  "+ errorThrown,
        _messageBlockWidth: "350px"
    });

    $('div#_StatusMessage').on('dialogclose', function (event) {
        window.location = "/SystemCore/SystemCoreHome";
    });
});
```

});

### razor form

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNewFunctionNavigation", "SystemCore", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "NewFunctionNavigationForm" }))
    {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
         ... my fields here
   <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default _formButton" />
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default _formButton" onclick="CancelPage();" />
                </div>
   </div>
}
```

### controller method

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateNewFunctionNavigation()
    {

        return PartialView("CreateNewNavigation_Partial");
    }


 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateNewFunctionNavigation(CreateFunctionNavigation_SP_Map model )
    {


        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                 _FN_Services_a2.CreateFunctionNavigation(model);

                 return Json(new { Response = "Success" });
            }
            catch (DataException ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable To Create New Function Navigation" + ex);
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
        return PartialView("CreateNewNavigation_Partial", model);
        //return Json(new { Url = Url.Action("CreateNewNavigation_Partial", model) });

    } //end
```

Comment: Your specifying the return type as `dataType: "JSON",` but your method returns `html`. What is the point of this since you immediately redirect to another view. Just make a normal submit and if the model is not valid, return the view, otherwise `return RedirectToAction("SystemCoreHome", "SystemCore");` Ajax is pointless here

Comment: You mean data is not posted or model is not binding. Remove datatype and contenttype property from ajax call.

Comment: @StephenMuecke is right, AJAX is unnecessary here. To serialize the form data, you simply need to do `$('#NewFunctionNavigationForm').serialize();`

Comment: I am doing so that I can capture messages including successes, fail or record already exists

Comment: If you do a normal post and return the view because of model errors (or you add your own ModelState errors), then those errors will be displayed (and displayed properly as opposed to just some arbitrary message in a dialog). And what happens when the ModelState is invalid - your script fails and the user gets a confusing "Error In Creating Record!" message.